# Linking directly to a CSS tab

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, tabs

I'm trying to figure out how to give somebody a direct link to a CSS  tab on my page, but giving them **pagename.html#tab2** doesn't work.  If it's possible to do this without a script, it would be best, but I'm open to anything at this point.
BTW, feel free to tear apart my code!  I'm just learning how to do this, so it may not be as efficient as it should be!  Thanks!

```css
/* Tabs */

input  /*hide radio buttons */
{
  display: none;
}

input+label  /* show labels in line */
{
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

input~.tab  /* show contents only for selected tab */
{
  display: none;
}

#tab1:checked~.tab.content1,
#tab2:checked~.tab.content2 {
  display: block;
}

input+label {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  background: #101010;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}

input+label:hover {
  background: #212121;
}

input:checked+label {
  background: transparent;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #292929;
}

input~.tab {
  border-top: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: #292929;color: #b2b2b2;line-height: 1.5em;font-family: Mulish,sans-serif;">
  <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab1" checked="checked" />
  <label for="tab1">Tab 1</label>
  <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab2" />
  <label for="tab2">Tab 2</label>
  <div class="tab content1">
    <p>Tab content 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab content2">
    <p>Tab content 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Something like [`:target`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/t/target/)  might work.

Comment: I don't think so, the checked attribute cannot be set through css that I know of. Maybe you could stye the page based on the hash, but then you lose the functionality of the input buttons. I think you need a script here. I will formulate an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify

```
<input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab1" checked />
```

then this radio button will be checked by default when the page is loaded. If you want the other tab to be checked you can do that by getting the hash from the URL and then checking it programmatically like so

```
<script>
// this will be #tag2 in your case
let hash = document.location.hash;

// remove the hash sign
hash = hash.slice(1, hash.length);

let tab = document.getElementById( hash );

// check the required input element
tab.setAttribute('checked', 'checked');

</script>
```

You will want to include this script near the end of your body, well after the input elements are loaded.

Comment: Thanks, @mrmonsieur! So I added that, then went to pagename.com#tab2 and it didn't work.  Am I using the incorrect syntax?

Comment: Sorry about that I was imprecise and too lazy to verify but now I have

Comment: The edited answer worked for me and did what it is supposed to

Comment: Thank you so much!  That worked!  I would upvote it, but I don't have the reputation cred yet.  :(

Answer (score 1):

use

```
scrollIntoView()
```

check this doc on it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

I hope this helps